# Switch on/off Promtail which runs in docker container in k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, sidecar, promtail

Current monitoring of log-files of an java application running on wildfly consist of Loki, Promtail and Graphana.

The java application and Promtail run in separate containers in one k8s pod with shared volume and network. Whereas one Pomtail container is responsible for gathering logs from one java application, with which it is sharing the pod.
Promtail has a "Sidecar" logic, but is not marked as a k8s sidecar and has no defined lifecycle.

I want to make monitoring of application's logs optional and therefore, be able to control Promtail container and switch it on/off on demand.
So far I did not find a best practice solution how to do so. If anyone has knowledge in this area, I will appreciate any idea or advise.